# Use https with WSL and local Symfony web server

Tags: certificate, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How do I get my Edge web browser to trust my local development Symfony website running in WSL?

I am coding a website on Windows 10 using WSL 1 (Windows Subsystem for Linux) with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  I am using [Symfony local web server](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html).  I would like to use https, testing the website at the URL https://localhost:8000  But web browsers say the website is not trusted.  Edge (Chromium-based) shows a web page with these errors:

```
    Your connection isn't private
    Attackers might be trying to steal your information from localhost
    (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).
    NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

Examining the certificate shows the error:
This CA Root certificate is not trusted because it is not in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store.

How do I prevent these errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you install the `symfony` command in WSL, the [instructions](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html#enabling-tls) say to run the command `symfony server:ca:install`.  This creates some self-signed certificate files in  `~/.symfony/certs/`  The Windows 10 processes such as Edge need to be told about this certificate using the following procedure.

```
Copy ~/.symfony/certs/rootCA.pem to your Windows 10 Documents directory.
In Windows 10, search for "mmc" and run the Microsoft Management Console command.
Select File > Add Snap-in "Certificates" for current user.
Expand "Certificates - Current User"
Expand Trusted Root Certification Authorities
Click Certificates folder
Select Action > All Tasks > Import...
In the File chooser popup, select file filter All Files (*.*) and choose rootCA.pem
You will be prompted with a security warning. Verify the cert listed is the self-signed cert and click yes
(You may need to restart your browser or computer.)
```

This answer was adapted from [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27316292/This-CA-root-certificate-is-not-trusted-to-enable-trust-install-this-certificate-in-the-trusted-root-certification-authorities-store.html)